# Why do we need to create a Interrupt vector table?

Tags: linux, arm, interrupt, avr, bootloader

I have read in some tutorials in net that the branching address of the interrupts are hardwired already .
They why do we need to create the IVT in the bootloader?

Comment: It's unlikely that they are all "hardwired", unless they point to a region providing just enough space for you to encode a jump elsewhere.    A design that pointed to a set or regions each providing enough space to write actually service routines would be either very constraining or very wasteful, since different applications will need different length routines.  Putting both "arm" and "avr" tags on this makes it hard to answer, as those are quite different architectures.

Answer (score 8):

The issue is that you want to have different hardware detected events or exceptions or interrupts whatever you want to call them.  And you want to have the opportunity to have separate code run based on that event.  The hardware has to somehow hand off control to those separate routines.  So for each processor architecture there is a solution. Often we just call it an interrupt vector table based on history but some may call it an exception table, and in the case of arm (most not all arms) is it really a table since it is not a list of addresses but actual instructions?

The address where the code executes is generally not hardcoded, in the case of ARM yes, but in general an interrupt vector table is a list of addresses, the location of this table and each entry in the table is a fixed address but in some way the software folks fill in that table with addresses to code.  The hardware for those situations detects the event, based on that event reads from memory at a known to all location, that location contains an address and it starts fetching/running at that address.  hardcoding addresses to execute would end up with the arm situation or something like it, it wouldnt make sense for example to have reset at 0x0000 and prefetch abort at 0x1000, and data abort at 0x2000, etc.   you want that table of instructions or addresses to be nice and tight.  Unless patented you could create an arm like table for pretty much any architecture, maybe more than four bytes per exception, but you could still do it.  Or just do the address thing.

ARM has switched to the traditional address thing in the Cortex-M, but unlike the traditional address thing there are dozens to potentially hundreds of individual vectors (in a microcontroller!) every little thing has an entry point.  The reason being if you read in or between the lines of their docs is the cortex-m is designed so that you dont need assembly wrapped around your C handler, with a traditional processor an interrupt return is special and requires a special instruction for example, the entry of an interrupt often involved saving all the registers where the C calling convention for that processor may have not saved everything.  So some assembly was required and/or compiler specific directives to get the compiler to do it for you.  with the cortex m you can have a normal, not special at all, C function and simply put the address to that C function in the huge interrupt vector table at the right place.

Why in the bootloader.

- the bootloader is generally non-volatile code, flash/rom.
- the bootloader handles the reset event
- In order to be able to boot the processor you need at least enough of the IVT In flash/rom to find the reset handler.

So you will typically carve out a chunk of address space at and around the vector table address for that architecture and put non volatile memory there.  Often nearby but not required you need a chunk of address space to put a non-volatile memory for the reset handler, you simply cant boot the processor otherwise (if the processor uses an address in a table to find the reset handler, a typical solution).

Since you already have one item of the vector table in flash/rom you put the rest there. and call the whole thing the bootloader.  Once booted you may wish to have the vector table volatile so that you can have interrupts point at an operating system based handler that the bootloader loaded rather than it being non-volatile pointed at the bootloaders handler or some hardcoded address in space.  And there are a great many different ways to solve that problem, general categories of switching the memory controller to point at ram (After up and running), to having the bootloader handlers use some sort of indirection to some ram locations except for reset.  How you actually implement that, etc varies.  with an MMU in your system for example you can easily re-map the vector table to ram...

Answer (score 6):

The *interrupt vector table* is more than just *interrupts*.  It is also called the **exception** table.  There are two general forms,

1. Function pointers
2. Fixed code entry points.

For instance, on a 68K the value at address 0x8 might be used as a **data fault** function pointer.  On traditional ARM cpus, a *data fault* exception will set the program counter to address 0x8.  The interrupt handler might be at offset 0x10, etc.  The **table** handles more than interrupts.  On the ARM,

1. reset
2. undefined instruction
3. supervisor handler (SWI)
4. prefetch handler
5. data abort handler
6. interrupt handler
7. fast interrupt handler

As you can see there is more than one entry.  By using a table, the CPU hardware can be minimal and only have to know one address versus seven or more.  In older ARM systems, the vector table can be high or low (0xffff0000 or 0x0) based on the way a vendor configures it.  In newer (Cortex-A at least), you can specify the table address with the `VBAR`.

> Then why do we need to create the IVT in the bootloader?

The offset maybe fixed in the chip.  The boot loader needs to put code there so that there is something to handle it.

Lets say we have a mailbox at our house.  The post man puts mail in the box.  We go to the box and remove the mail.  The mail box is the vector table location.  The post man is the CPU.  We are the code in the vector table.  The mail box and vector table locations are at fixed places.

Comment: The constant 0x8 and 0x10 are made up and are just for illustration.  The offsets of *vector entry* will be different for each CPU type.